# Joystick operation for a gazebo ros youbot

Tags: ros, turtlesim, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have created a node just like teleop_joy using [ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode). It publishes a topic */joy* and the type of message is *sensor_msgs/Joy*. My youbot has a topic */cmd_vel* and the type of message is *geometry_msgs/Twist*. I want to move the youbot using joystick by subscribing /cmd_vel to /joy but the type of messages are different. How can I do this? Any ideas please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249583/joystick-operation-for-a-gazebo-ros-youbot/) by [manju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27548/manju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) on 2016-12-07**:
Have you checked out this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode) shows, you need to subscribe to your topic `/joy` and then assign the data from the joystick (with a proper normalization/scaling) to a `Twist` message which you then can publish to your `/cmd_vel` topic in order to move your youBot.

The tutorial shows an example of the callback, i.e. where you listen to the joystick data and then assign it to the `Twist` message:

```
void TeleopTurtle::joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy)
{
  geometry_msgs::Twist twist;
  twist.angular.z = a_scale_*joy->axes[angular_];
  twist.linear.x = l_scale_*joy->axes[linear_];
  vel_pub_.publish(twist);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) with karma: 136 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-09**:
And as much fun as it is to write these things ourselves, for others that want to *reuse* something existing, take a look at [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy).